# Dagger 2: Cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I just started learning dagger2 and faced a strange issue that looks like a bug to me. Here's the module:

```
@Module
public class SimpleModule {

    @Provides
    Cooker providerCooker() {

        return new Cooker("tom", "natie");
    }
}
```

Component:

```
@Component(modules = SimpleModule.class)
public interface SimpleComponent {

    void inject(DaggerTestActivity activity);

}
```

Interface:

```
public interface CoffeeMaker {

    String makeCoffee();
}
```

Implementation:

```
  public class SimpleMaker implements CoffeeMaker {
    
        Cooker mCooker;
      
        @Inject
        public SimpleMaker(Cooker cooker) {
    
            this.mCooker = cooker;
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public String makeCoffee() {
    
            return mCooker.makeCoffee();
        }
    }
```

Cooker :

```
public class Cooker {

    String name; 
    String coffeeKind;


    public Cooker(String name, String coffeeKind) {
        this.name = name;
        this.coffeeKind = coffeeKind;
    }
    
   public  String  makeCoffee() {
  
        return name + "make" + coffeeKind; 
    }

}
```

Coffee machine:

```
public class CoffeeMachine {

    CoffeeMaker mMaker;

    @Inject
    public CoffeeMachine(CoffeeMaker coffeeMaker) {

        this.mMaker = coffeeMaker;
    }

    public String makeCoffee() {

        return mMaker.makeCoffee();
    }
}
```

Just it. I use it in the activity. Faced strange issue here:

```
    @Inject
    CoffeeMachine mCoffeeMachine;
```

The error I'm getting from the Dagger 2 compiler is the following:

```
Error:(14, 10) com.wyyc.daggertest.CoffeeMaker cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
com.wyyc.zqqworkproject.DaggerTestActivity.mCoffeeMachine
[injected field of type: com.wyyc.daggertest.CoffeeMachine mCoffeeMachine]
com.wyyc.daggertest.CoffeeMachine.<init>(com.wyyc.daggertest.CoffeeMaker coffeeMaker)
```

All this situation looks very strange, and I'd like to hear some input from more experienced Dagger 2 users.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Your `CoffeeMachine` needs `CoffeeMaker`. And you have declared that Dagger will take care of providing that dependency to the `CoffeeMachine` by annotating the constructor with `@Inject`. But Dagger says:

> CoffeeMaker cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method

Because you haven't specified anywhere how `CoffeeMaker` object should be created. `@Inject`ing `SimpleMaker` is not enough, because `SimpleMaker` != `CoffeeMaker`. So, you have to specify explicitly, that when Dagger wants `CoffeeMaker` then provide him `SimpleMaker`.

Change your module to this:

```
@Module
public class SimpleModule {

    @Provides
    Cooker providerCooker() {
        return new Cooker("tom", "natie");
    }

    @Provides
    CoffeeMaker provideCoffeeMaker(Cooker cooker) {
        return new SimpleMaker(cooker);
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks, I want to know why this，I hope you can give me some idea 。thank you

Comment: grateful for your answer patiently.Do you have a good materials for learning dagger2 ?  Can you give me under reference ?

Comment: https://android.jlelse.eu/practical-guide-to-dagger-76398948a2ea
So far the best explanation i have come across for Dagger 2

Comment: i had similar problem, but i had a different return type of my provider method in my module and expecting a context  back in component class

Comment: @azizbekian If you have time, maybe you can help me with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58747371/how-to-inject-the-creation-of-a-broadcastreceiver-object-in-fragment-using-dagge). Thanks

Answer (score 4):

In my case I missed one module in `@Component` (in multi-module app). Thanks to @azizbekian.

```
@Component(
    modules = [
        ApiModule::class,
        SettingsModule::class,
        CoroutinesModule::class // <- I forgot one of these modules
    ],
    dependencies = [Api::class, NetworkProvider::class]
)
interface YourComponent {
```

Answer (score 3):

In a multi-module project this error may occur when a new module is added. To fix this you need to add new module to build.gradle(:app) dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':new_module')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a closer look at imports

Replace

```
import com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.dagger.Provides
import com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.dagger.Module
```

With

```
import dagger.Module
import dagger.Provides
```

Answer (score 0):

Had another case. I used lazy and didn't provide the import, so it took Kotlin `Lazy` instead of `dagger.Lazy`.

Once I added the dagger import the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

In Hilt my mistake was wrong `@InstallIn` component.                            I just change the component to appropriate one.
I changed from:

`@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)`

To:

`@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)`

Answer (score -1):

If you have this problem when everything seems correct it may be because you did some refactoring, clean the project and compile again.