# How to inject the creation of a BroadcastReceiver object in Fragment using Dagger2?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, broadcastreceiver, dagger-2, dagger

I need to inject the creation of `NetReceiver` object into my Fragment but I get the following error:

> error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.example.myapp.NetReceiver.OnNetCallback cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.

Let me show you what I have tried. This is my `NetReceiver` class:

```
public class NetReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private OnNetCallback onNetCallback;

    @Inject
    public NetReceiver(OnNetCallback onNetCallback) {
        this.onNetCallback = onNetCallback;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (someCondition) {
            onNetCallback.enableOperation(true);
        }
    }

    public interface OnNetCallback {
        void enableOperation(boolean isOk);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I want to inject in the constructor a `NetCallback` object. I have also created a Module class that looks like this:

```
@Module
public abstract class NetReceiverModule {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector //Error?!?!?!?!
    abstract NetReceiver.OnNetCallback provideOnNetCallback();

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    static NetReceiver provideNetReceiver(NetReceiver.OnNetCallback onNetCallback) {
        return new NetReceiver(onNetCallback);
    }
}
```

This is how my fragment look liked when it worked:

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements NetReceiver.OnNetCallback {
    private NetReceiver netReceiver;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Inflate View
        netReceiver = new NetReceiver(this); //Worked
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
        mainActivity.registerReceiver(netReceiver, intentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
        mainActivity.unregisterReceiver(netReceiver);
    }
}
```

And this is how it looks when it is not working:

```
public class MapFragment extends DaggerFragment implements NetReceiver.OnNetCallback {
    @Inject NetReceiver netReceiver;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Inflate View
        //netReceiver = new NetReceiver(this); //Worked
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
        mainActivity.registerReceiver(netReceiver, intentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
        mainActivity.unregisterReceiver(netReceiver);
    }
}
```

Comment: `OnNetCallback` is an interface and by defining `abstract NetReceiver.OnNetCallback provideOnNetCallback();` dagger doesn't know which implementation to return. What you want to do is `@Binds abstract fun bindOnNetCallback(callback: MapFragment): OnNetCallback`. But I wouldn't design it this way so that I have to inject fragment in broadcast receiver. Maybe you could have an interactor/repository/localdatasource as the connection between `MapFragment` and `NetReceiver`

Comment: @sonnet Can you please provide an answer for that, so I can see the code better? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `Dagger2` cannot do magic. How it should know from where to provide a `OnNetCallback`. Your fragment extends this callback but neither its constructor is annotated with `@Inject` annotation(because you are not advised to create explicit fragment constructors) nor it is provided with `@Provides` annotated method in your module, nor `OnNetCallback` is bind with `MapFragment` via  `@Bind` annotated method which is a "must be" when you trying to inject interface like this along with a `@Qualifier`.

But that is not the main issue.

Even if you will manage to do all the previous stuff correctly it will still not work because there will be a circular dependency - `MapFragment` depends on `NetReceiver`, `NetReceiver` depends on `OnNetCallback`, `OnNetCallback` is a `MapFragment`, thus `NetReceiver` depends on `MapFragment`. Dagger won't let you do it.

If you want your `MapFragment` to implement `OnNetCallback` I would suggest something like:

```
public class NetReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public OnNetCallback onNetCallback;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (someCondition && onNetCallback!= null) {
            onNetCallback.enableOperation(true);
        }
    }

    public interface OnNetCallback {
        void enableOperation(boolean isOk);
    }
}


public class MapFragment extends DaggerFragment implements NetReceiver.OnNetCallback {

    @Inject NetReceiver netReceiver;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Inflate View
        netReceiver.onNetCallback = this
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
        mainActivity.registerReceiver(netReceiver, intentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
        mainActivity.unregisterReceiver(netReceiver);
    }
}
```

If you want it to be injected - create some separate from `Fragment` implementation of `OnNetCallback` and @Provide it in module and inject it into fragment.

Also `@ContributesAndroidInjector` should be used for the injeters but not for the injectees - it tells `Dagger` that this class should be injected with some stuff described with `@Inject`, `@Provides` and `@Bind` annotations.

Also I would recommend you to read an [official guide](https://dagger.dev/users-guide) regarding `Dagger2` and [its usage for Android](https://dagger.dev/android).

Hope it helps.

Comment: `via @Bind annotated method which is a "must be" when you trying to inject interface` It's not a "must be". You can provide different interface implementations using @Provides

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. As I understand, all I have to do is to make the `onNetCallback` field  public in `NetReceiver`, remove the constructor and use `netReceiver.onNetCallback = this` but should I keep both methods in my `NetReceiverModule` class? Or a single one? Or none?

Comment: You may leave both but the first one should look like ```@ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract fun injectMapFragment(): MapFragment```

Comment: @PaulOst I think it's to complex for me. I'll do try to do more attempts to solve this and if it's this way I'll accept your answer. Voted-up for your idea. Thanks