# cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method. public abstract static class SingletonC implements MyApplication_GeneratedInjector error

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2, clean-architecture

I want to learn clean architecture and I'm using hilt for di. Once I had java.lang.RuntimeException:

```
 Unable to instantiate application com.example.cleanarchitecture.MainActivity package com.example.cleanarchitecture: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.cleanarchitecture.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Application
```

error I've changed SingletonComponent to ActivityComponent now I have the error that I mention at title in my application.

My module is like that;

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
class ProfileDetailModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun providesProfileDetailRepository(dataSource: ProfileDataSource): ProfileRepository {

        return ProfileRepositoryImpl(dataSource)
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun providesProfileDataSource(profileApiService: ProfileApiService): ProfileDataSource {

        return ProfileDataSource(profileApiService)
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun providesProfileDetailApiService(retrofit: Retrofit): ProfileApiService =
        retrofit.create(ProfileApiService::class.java)

    @Module
    @InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
    object AppModule {


        @Provides
            fun provideApplicationContext(@ActivityContext activity: Activity): Activity {
            return activity
        }
    }




}
```

and my repository is ;

```
interface ProfileRepository {

    suspend fun getUser(url:String): ProfileResponse
}
```

and this is my domain class;

```
class GetUserProfile @Inject constructor(
    private val profileRepository: ProfileRepository
): MutableLiveData<ProfileResponse>(){

    companion object {
        private const val URL =
            "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1"
    }

    data class Params(
        val id: Int,
        val name: String,
        val username: String,
        val email: String,
        val phone: String,
    )


     fun execute(
        viewModel: ProfileDetailViewModel,
        input: Params?
    ): MutableLiveData<ProfileResponse> {
        return MutableLiveData<ProfileResponse>().apply {
            input?.let {
                viewModel.viewModelScope.launch {
                    value =
                        profileRepository.getUser(URL+it.id+it.name+it.username+it.email+it.phone)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Want to learn clean architecture so I have many question marks in my head.

Looked that question and cant helped me ; [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43116825/dagger-2-cannot-be-provided-without-an-provides-annotated-method/43117280#4311728)

Answer (score 0):

Can you check by removing AppModule at the last of your file. For the app, AppModule has to be singleton as it's one for the entire app container.

Comment: Did you remove the Dagger Implementation ? Also try invalidating cache.

Comment: it occurs another ; error: com.example.cleanarchitecture.ProfileDetailModule is abstract and has instance @Provides methods. Consider making the methods static or including a non-abstract subclass of the module instead.
  public abstract static class SingletonC implements MyApplication_GeneratedInjector,